# Raster (rather than vector) issue with some math symbols, such as \in or parentheses () inside math mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting, pdf, compiling

When I compile the following code in TexStudio

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
    Let's see $(\in),$ but $X$ or $\beta$.
\end{document}
```

It is shown in the PDF this way

[image]

As you can see, math symbols like `$X$` and `$\beta$` are printed in a vector format (like I want), but other symbols like `$\in$` or the parentheses `$()$` are raster. Do you know what's the problem here?

Lots of thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle , but I can´t find that package in MikTex. Maybe I'm too noob, btw. I do have cm-super package installed.

Comment: in texlive 2021 your example only uses type1 scalable fonts, check you have the cm-super font collection installed

Comment: sorry typo in first comment I retyped it, show the log of your test it should end `{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t
1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10
.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathabx-type1/matha
10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095
.pfb>
Output written on bb626.pdf (1 page, 27212 bytes)`  (with different paths) but showing `pfb` fonts not `pk`

Comment: @David so what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: You seem to be lacking the `mathabx` fonts in Type1 format. Install https://miktex.org/packages/mathabx-type1

Comment: you should be able to update the fonts in miktex but I don't use miktex so can't give detailed instructions on its package management