# Prettier \in symbol

Tags: symbols

Probably something that has been asked before, I just can't seem to find it.

Currently using these packages:

```
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}[fleqn]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
\end{document}
```

The $\in$ symbol just doesn't look good.
Are there any alternatives?

Looks like this: [image]

Ideally I would be able to only change the \in symbol and nothing else

Comment: Would be better if you include a minimal working example, not just the preamble.

Comment: Try [Which OpenType Math fonts are available? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) ?

Comment: you should show an example with x\in X or similar and say what you do not like. None of the code that you posted is related to your question except `\usepackage{mathabx}` if you do not like the mathabx font pick a different one, there are dozens of math fonts available.

Comment: it is hard to tell from your image but if your \in is pixilated from a bitmap font make sure you have the type1 mathabx fonts installed see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628321/1090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a more reasonable test document without the unrelated packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
\end{document}
```

With `\usepackage{amsfonts,mathabx}`

[image]

With `\usepackage{amsfonts}`

[image]

With `\usepackage{stix2}`

[image]

With `\usepackage{newtxmath}`

[image]

There are dozens more math fonts available and no purely objective way of choosing between them. Note however that a font is a collective combined work of design, you should almost always choose an entire math font not select different fonts for different symbols.